# How do i call setState multiple times (e.g. in a loop)?

Tags: react-hooks

I am building a react app which is executing a complicated web-assembly process. The web-assembly implements basically a loop, and each iteration i need to write something in a output-textfield. The value of the textfield is bound to a state called output.

The problem is, that when i call setOutput subsequently (in the loop), the textfield does only re-render after the last setOutput. (expected behavior of useState hook)
In the web-assembly, i am always setting all the lines, therefore i do not depend on the previous state...

I have worked out a workaround which is using a class component, because here i can await setState, and then calling the next setState.

I don't want to mix functional components with class components. Is there another way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functional form of setState, which accepts a function that updates the state. This way, you can call setState multiple times in the loop, and each time it will correctly update the state and trigger a re-render.

Here's an example:

```
// initialize output state to an empty string
const [output, setOutput] = useState('');

// loop through some data and update the output state
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  setOutput(prevOutput => prevOutput + data[i] + '\n');
}
```

In the example, the loop updates the output state by appending some data to the previous output value and adding a newline character. The **prevOutput** parameter of the update function represents the previous state value. By using this parameter, you ensure that the updates are correctly applied in sequence, even if they are not batched together.

Note that using setState in a loop can be an expensive operation, as it triggers a re-render each time. You may want to consider batching updates with the **useEffect** hook or using a different approach, depending on your specific use case.

Comment: that doesn't trigger a re-rendering in each iteration...